# UIAutomation won't return value of a children element

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid, ui-automation, textblock

Following is my control view in Inspect tool and I am trying to return value from Text-Block under the tree :

[Control in Inspect tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HAem.jpg)

In my WPF windows application, a datagrid has rows and columns and trying to get the text values for specific row and column. The first row has the text value (timestamp) as the Text-Block under sub tree.

Inspect control properties are :

datagrid - Datagrid

Log - DataItemControlType

Item - UIA_CustomControlType (DataGridCell)

Custom - UIA_CustomControlType (DataGridCell)

text - UIA_TextControlTypeID

I can get the total no of rows but unable to get the text value.

```
var gridChilds = grid.LowLevelAutomationObject.FindAll(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition).OfType<AutomationElement>();
var rows = gridChilds.Count() ;

List<AutomationElement> messages = new List<AutomationElement>();
            TreeWalker walker = new TreeWalker(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem));
             AutomationElement ae = grdControl as AutomationElement;
            AutomationElement row = walker.GetFirstChild(ae);

                messages.Add(row);
            row = walker.GetNextSibling(row);
            string result = Convert.ToString(row);
            return result ;
```

I tried some solutions from online help for similar questions but none worked for my example. I am new to C# coding and the tool,so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the screen shot of inspect it looks like you want the name property for the cell. So the code would look something like this. I started at your grid control and I also assumed that the rows had a class name of "Record" since most rows in grids will have a class name of "Record".

```
AutomationElement dataGrid = grdControl as AutomationElement;
AutomationElement outerRow = dataGrid.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Record"));
AutomationElement innerRow = outerRow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Record"));
AutomationElement custom = innerRow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "custom"));
AutomationElement text = custom.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "text"));

return text.Name;
```

Comment: Max Young, Thank you so much, I was able to get a work around something similar to the above solution you provided. Something which will be "nice to have is" to loop at custom level and based on the row number I give, it should get the text value. But thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: No problem if you need any help with UI Automation feel free to message me. It is horrible to learn UI Automation with the resources available.

Comment: Max Young, Is there a way I can send my code into your Inbox messages for a different question. Not sure if SO has ability to post private message to users as I do not want to publish my code in public. Please let me know.

Comment: @cherryS You can get ahold of my on gitter. Just message me in the https://gitter.im/FlaUI/Lobby.